# Mysqli code changes

Tags: php, mysqli

i am adapting this code to Mysqli, but is gives an error, i cannot see the error, please help.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml ('title', 'artist', 'duration') VALUES ('$title', '$artist', '$duration')";        
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

the old code worked good:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `test_xml`  (`title`, `artist`, `duration`)"
            . "VALUES ('$title', '$artist', '$duration')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Use backticsk for column names not quotes.See the difference?Also learn about prepared statements,mysqli is not more secure by default.

Comment: There is a difference between a backtick ` and a single quote `'`

Comment: *"the old code worked good:"* - So use that and use `$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);`. Plus, in case you haven't been told about it (edit: Oops, you have by Mihai, my bad), or have any knowledge of; your code is open to [**SQL injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: whwre is your mysqli_connect initialization?

Comment: *"i cannot see the error"* - That's because you're not checking for them. Add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` and you will see them.

Answer (score 1):

Risking downvotes, but I can't comment at my level so in order to try help I'll assume the question is "how can I see the error" and try answer that, as there's not much else to go on;

First, is $con created successfully?

```
$con = new mysqli("sql server hostname or ip", "user", "password", "schema/db name");
        if($con->connect_errno > 0)
            {
                die('Unable to connect to database [' . $con->connect_error . ']');
            }
```

As per comments, problem solved due to ' vs ` for column names.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml (`title`, `artist`, `duration`) VALUES ('$title', '$artist', '$duration')";        

if(!$result = $con->query($sql)) {
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');
} else {
  echo "Successful query.";
       }
```

this portion was really to include the error handling to see what the error was.

Comment: `('title', 'artist', 'duration')` that's incorrect. Those are columns, and not to be treated as string (values).

Comment: @user2213361 - Look at the comments under the OP's question. You haven't gotten downvoted "yet", but if you don't fix it, you will.

Comment: seemed kinda pointless after the problem was solved, but fixed anyway.  For interest sake, the error that would have been thrown was "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''title....at line 1

Comment: Well, you did submit a (now) correct answer, so may as well leave it intact. @user2213361

Comment: By the way, I fixed a syntax error in your answer. It's `$con->error` and not `$sql->error`. The DB connection is to be passed as the variable and not the query.

Answer (score 0):

ok it was in the line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml ('title', 'artist', 'duration')
```

in the columms,
the ' must be ` like @Mihai and @RiggsFolly said.